# Google's "define: " through an API?

Tags: json, google-api, google-search-api

I want to get the result of searches that use special features in Google, like "define: [phrase]" and I can't seem to find relevant information about this.

Does anyone knows where I can get the data in JSON format (like the rest of Google's APIs) without scraping the results page manually?

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: @Emanuel You might want to check for the updated answer below...

Comment: So Google Dictionary is no longer a thing so how can the answer to this question be possible now?

Comment: I created https://dictionaryapi.dev, you can take a look at that, it is multilingual dictionary API, which provide data from google. Source code is on github.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wish I had not set a bounty for this, because I stumbled upon the answer a few days later and it is really simple.

Here is URL to call if you want a definition to **love**:

> http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=love

You will get a response stream containing JSONP, with the following contents ("prettified" for learning purposes, API returns all in one line):

```
a(
    {
       "query":"love",
       "sourceLanguage":"en",
       "targetLanguage":"en",
       "primaries":[
          {
             "type":"headword",
             "terms":[
                {
                   "type":"text",
                   "text":"love",
                   "language":"en",
                   "labels":[
                      {
                         "text":"Noun",
                         "title":"Part-of-speech"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"phonetic",
                   "text":"/lÉ™v/",
                   "language":"und"
                },
                {
                   "type":"sound",
                   "text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/love.mp3",
                   "language":"und"
                }
             ],
             "entries":[
                {
                   "type":"related",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"loves",
                         "language":"und",
                         "labels":[
                            {
                               "text":"plural"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"An intense feeling of deep affection",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"babies fill parents with intense feelings of \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"their \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e for\x3c/b\x3e their country",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A deep romantic or sexual attachment to someone",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"it was \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e at first sight",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"they were both \x3cb\x3ein \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e with\x3c/b\x3e her",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"we were slowly \x3cb\x3efalling in \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e\x3c/b\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A personified figure of \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e, often represented as Cupid",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A great interest and pleasure in something",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"his \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e for\x3c/b\x3e football",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"we share a \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e of\x3c/b\x3e music",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"Affectionate greetings conveyed to someone on one\x27s behalf",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A formula for ending an affectionate letter",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"take care, lots of \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e, Judy",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A person or thing that one \x3cem\x3eloves\x3c/em\x3e",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"she was \x3cb\x3ethe \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e of his life\x3c/b\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"their two great \x3cem\x3eloves\x3c/em\x3e are tobacco and whiskey",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"A friendly form of address",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"it\x27s all right, \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"Used to express affectionate approval for someone",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"don\x27t fret, there\x27s a \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"(in tennis, squash, and some other sports) A score of zero; nil",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e fifteen",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"he was down two sets to \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "type":"headword",
             "terms":[
                {
                   "type":"text",
                   "text":"love",
                   "language":"en",
                   "labels":[
                      {
                         "text":"Verb",
                         "title":"Part-of-speech"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"phonetic",
                   "text":"/lÉ™v/",
                   "language":"und"
                },
                {
                   "type":"sound",
                   "text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/love.mp3",
                   "language":"und"
                }
             ],
             "entries":[
                {
                   "type":"related",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"loved",
                         "language":"und",
                         "labels":[
                            {
                               "text":"past participle"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"loves",
                         "language":"und",
                         "labels":[
                            {
                               "text":"3rd person singular present"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"loving",
                         "language":"und",
                         "labels":[
                            {
                               "text":"present participle"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"loved",
                         "language":"und",
                         "labels":[
                            {
                               "text":"past tense"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"Feel a deep romantic or sexual attachment to (someone)",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"do you \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e me?",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "type":"meaning",
                   "terms":[
                      {
                         "type":"text",
                         "text":"Like very much; find pleasure in",
                         "language":"en"
                      }
                   ],
                   "entries":[
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"I\x27d \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e a cup of tea, thanks",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"I just \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e dancing",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "type":"example",
                         "terms":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"a fun-\x3cem\x3eloving\x3c/em\x3e girl",
                               "language":"en"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
,200,null)
```

Google Dictionary API returns in the form of a callback function (JSONP). Before you can process the JSON within the function call, you have to strip out the callback function data.

That means removing everything before the first `{` and everything after the last `}`.

After this you are done! That's all information you need and it's basically the same (actually a little more!) information when you search Google for `define love`.

Comment: From the JSON response above, what does **\x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e** means?

Comment: Same Question, Please Define \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e?
this is unwanted string and I want to remove all this type of codes/string. Is there any list avilable of this type of codes so we can erase all of them from our output.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this! I was considering paying the $100 a month that the Oxford English Dictionary charge for their API! And WordNik's API is creaky.

Comment: Though not quite relevant, Is there any site using this json call.

Comment: were you able to parse this json?

Comment: Looks like they got rid of it today.

Comment: The response was relevant to it's date, but it appear to no longer work.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary gives an api with 1000 free queries each day: http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary.htm

Comment: @aardvarkk See my answer below.

Comment: @Eli I have created dictionary api from google, I have posted it as an answer below.

Comment: @ZackZatkin-Gold I also needed Google Dictionary API for my project, it was not present so I decided to create one. See the answer below.

Answer (score 8):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
word = "democracy"
url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define%20' + word + '#cns=1'
response = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"})
html = response.content
final_soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
everyThing = final_soup.select("div._Jig")
for line in everyThing:
    print("-",line.text)
```

I wrote this script to get the definition of a word from google.
Hope it helps but its not using any API.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming back to this, all previous answers seem to be broken. Here's what I have working as of april 2022:

```
import bs4
import requests


def definition(word):
    URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=define+" + word
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    first_find = soup.find('ol', class_='yRG22b v7pIac')
    if (first_find is not None):
        return first_find.find('div', class_='BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd').getText()
    return None
```

definition(word) returns a string which is the first definition result if you were to type "define (word)" into google. If google has no definition for that word, it returns None. Apologies if I violate any python standard practices, I'm a beginner to this language.

I'm assuming this will break in a month when google slightly modifies their html.