# Why does JSON.parse choke on encoded characters in nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, unicode

I'm attempting to look up the word "flower" in [Google's dictionary semi-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859794/googles-define-through-an-api). Source:

https://gist.github.com/DelvarWorld/0a83a42abbc1297a6687

Long story short, I'm calling JSONP with a callback paramater then regexing it out.

But it hits this snag:

```
undefined:1
ple","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"I stopped to buy Bridget some \x3cem\x3ef
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token x
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Google is serving me escaped HTML characters, which is fine, but `JSON.parse` cannot handle them?? What's weirding me out is this works just fine:

```
$ node

> JSON.parse( '{"a":"\x3cem"}' )
  { a: '<em' }
```

I don't get why my thingle is crashing

**Edit** These are all nice informational repsonses, but none of them help me get rid of the stacktrace.

Comment: Take a look at string in http://json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\xHH` is not part of JSON, but is part of JavaScript. It is equivalent to `\u00HH`. Since the built-in `JSON` doesn't seem to support it and I doubt you'd want to go through the trouble of modifying a non-built-in JSON implementation, you might just want to run the code in a sandbox and collect the resulting object.

Comment: Another hack for if you need to parse a “nearly JSON” structure is to replace `\x` with `\u00` before parsing. This is slightly safer as it avoids eval'ing.

Comment: @bobince: Right; that's sort of why I included the “`\xHH` ≡ `\u00HH`” bit. The problem with that is that you have to be careful of other escapes, e.g., don't change `\\xHH` (which is the literal text `\xHH`) into `\\u00HH` (the literal text `\u00HH`). I, too, agree that `eval`ing is usually undesirable, but if you do it in a sandbox without access to…almost anything, with a timeout, it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://json.org, a string character in a JSON representation of string may be:

- any-Unicode-character-
     except-"-or--or-
     control-character
- \"
- \
- \/
- \b
- \f
- \n
- \r
- \t
- \u four-hex-digits

So according to that list, the "json" you are getting is malformed at \x3

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works is because these two are equivalent.

```
JSON.parse( '{"a":"\x3cem"}' )
```

and

```
JSON.parse( '{"a":"<em"}' )
```

you string is passed to `JSON.parse` already decoded since its a literal `\x3cem` is actually `<em`

Now,  \x*xx* is valid in JavaScript but not in JSON, according to http://json.org/ the only characters you can have after a `\` are `"\/bfnrtu`.

Answer (score 0):

answer is correct, but needs couple of modifications. you might wanna try this one: https://gist.github.com/Selmanh/6973863