# get all meanings of a word in json

Tags: json, dictionary, thesaurus

How can I get all meaning of a word in json response .Preferably without key/signing up/api key .If I type  test then all meaning of that word.

I tried :

but its not working.

```
<?php
$query = 'oracle';
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q='.$query.'&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de&client=te');
// var_dump($file);
$file = substr($file, 2, -10);
$file = preg_replace("/\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/", "", $file);
echo $file;
$json = json_decode($file);
var_dump($json);
?>
```

Even this is returning null.

I have tried Only the php above.I would like to knowif I can make rest call without api key just words which match the query word .Is there any rest call you have in mind.I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That link is broken [404] http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q=oracle&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de&client=te

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming server side

Get a copy of a dictionary in a computer friendly format i.e. http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/ (XML).
Store said dictionary in a database or in memory and perform a lookup.

Would then be trivial to provide a restful service returning all definitions for a particular word.

Also see: [Google's "define: " through an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859794/googles-define-through-an-api)

Comment: If you are not posting the answer, then add it under comments.

Comment: Also see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739285/english-dictionary-database-for-mysql-php

Comment: I have tried Only the php above.I would like to knowif I can make rest call without api key just words which match the query word .Is there any rest call you have in mind.

Comment: Edited answer as per Leos suggestion

Comment: Does the edit constitute an answer or should I delete and repost as a comment?